# Is there another way to show Export buttons in Yajra Datatables using laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, html, laravel-5.8, yajra-datatable

I am using Yajra Datatables to query a list of users server side. I added all the dependencies but the buttons are not showing. The buttons are copy, PDF, CSV and even custom buttons are showing. What I have tried is use different versions of JQuery but still nothing. When I just initialize the Datatable using an array of data coming from the view the buttons are showing and working fine but when I add the datasource as coming from a route and server side true the buttons are not showing. Anything am missing? Below is my code for server side processing which is not showing the buttons. I am also not getting console errors when I debug.

**Datasource**

```
    public function index(Request $request)


    if ($request->ajax()) {

    $users = User::select(
        "users.id", 
        "users.first_name",
        "users.last_name",
        "users.email",
        "users.created_at",
        "roles.name as role_name")
        ->join("roles", "roles.id", "=", "users.role_id")
        ->where("users.status", "=", 1)
        ->get();

        return Datatables::of($users)
                ->addIndexColumn()
                ->make(true);
    }

        return view('users/index');
}
```

**The table**

```
                                <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                              <thead>
                                <tr>
                                  <th>Email</th>
                                  <th>First Name</th>
                                  <th>Last Name</th>
                                  <th>Date Added</th>
                                </tr>
                              </thead>
                              <tbody>

                              </tbody>
                            </table>

<script>
  $(function () {
$("#example1").DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
            url: '{{ route('users.home') }}',
        },
    columns: [
        {data: 'email', name: 'email'},
        {data: 'first_name', name: 'first_name'},
        {data: 'last_name', name: 'last_name'},
        {
            data: "created_at",
            "render": function (value) {
                if (value === null) return "";
                return moment(value).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
            }
        }
    ],
  "responsive": false, "lengthChange": false, "autoWidth": false,
  "buttons": ["copy", "csv", "excel", "pdf", "print", "colvis"]
}).buttons().container().appendTo('#example1_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)');
  });
</script>
```

Below is my my CSS and JS libraries

**CSS**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('plugins/datatables-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('plugins/datatables-responsive/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('plugins/datatables-buttons/css/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css') }}">
```

**JS**

```
<script src="{{ asset('plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('plugins/datatables-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('plugins/jszip/jszip.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('plugins/pdfmake/pdfmake.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('plugins/pdfmake/vfs_fonts.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('plugins/datatables-buttons/js/buttons.html5.min.js') }}"></script>
```

When I loop through the table like below using php or blade the buttons are showing:

```
<?php
                    if(isset($users) && count($users)>0){ 
                      ?>
                            <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                              <thead>
                                <tr>
                                  <th>Email</th>
                                  <th>First Name</th>
                                  <th>Last Name</th>
                                </tr>
                              </thead>
                              <tbody>
                      <?php

                      foreach($users as $user){ 
                      ?>
                                <tr>
                                  <td><?php echo $user['email']; ?></td>
                                  <td><?php echo $user['first_name']; ?></td>
                                  <td><?php echo $user['last_name']; ?></td>
                                </tr>




                      <?php
                        
                      } ?>

                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <?php
                                  }else {
                                    echo "No Users Available";
                                  }
                    ?>
```

**Table Initialization**

```
<script>
    $("#example1").DataTable({
  "responsive": true, "lengthChange": false, "autoWidth": false,
  "buttons": ["copy", "csv", "excel", "pdf", "print", "colvis"]
}).buttons().container().appendTo('#example1_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)');


});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below. You are missing a DOM element of lBfrtip

```
<script>


$(function () {
$("#example1").DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    dom:'lBfrtip',
    ajax: {
            url: '{{ route('users.home') }}',
        },
    columns: [
        {data: 'email', name: 'email'},
        {data: 'first_name', name: 'first_name'},
        {data: 'last_name', name: 'last_name'},
        {
            data: "created_at",
            "render": function (value) {
                if (value === null) return "";
                return moment(value).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
            }
        }
    ],
  "responsive": false, "lengthChange": false, "autoWidth": false,
  "buttons": ["copy", "csv", "excel", "pdf", "print", "colvis"]
}).buttons().container().appendTo('#example1_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)');
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Let me try this